# How can I append string to y-axis data with tick and d3.format?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm making a pretty simple Stacked Bar Chart using C3.js. https://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html . I want to be able to append text to the values, specifically +"Mb" so that my end users know that those numbers indicate Megabits, and not anything else. I've added a useful y-axis label, but for my question, I'm wondering how to utilize d3.js to perform the formatting of the values.

I used d3.format which suggests I am able to append string, but haven't figured how to pull it off.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 2000, 2000, 4000],
            ['data2', 1300, 1000, 500],
            ['data3', 2000, 2000, 2500]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        y: {
            label: {
                text: 'Bandwidth Usage (Mb)',
                position: 'outer-middle'
            },
            tick: {
                format: d3.format('') + "mb"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This isn't working as expected, I'm getting "TypeError: this.tickFormat is not a function". Wondering if there are any c3 gurus out there than can help me with this problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a tick function as follows:

```
tick: 
      {
        format: function (d) {
            if ((d) > 0) {
                d = d + "Mb";
                }
            return d;
        }
      },
```

I have used >0 for d, so the "Mb" just gets appended to d if d is not 0, but you could also extend the code to automatically transform the input:

```
 tick: 
       {
         format: function (d) {
             if (((d / 1000) >= 1) & ((d / 1000) < 1000)) {
                  d = Math.round((d / 1000 )*100) / 100 + "Kb";
                  }
             else if ((d / 1000000) >= 1) {
                  d = Math.round((d / 1000000 )*100) / 100 + "Mb";
                  }
             return d;
          }
        },
```

By doing this, you could use untransformed data as input, and it will transform it to either "Kb" or "Mb" unit. 100 sets 2 digits after decimal point.